# Doubt- Number of ways to write an even number as sum of three primes powers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am studying the proof of Vinogradov's Theorem from Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory. I am stuck with the following

[image: Primes]

It writes that the formula is of little use when $N$ is even. However it mentions that the number of ways to write an even integer as sum of three primes is $O(N(\log N)^4)$. The hint is that one of the $k_i$ must be a power of $2$. I see why one of the $k_i$ is a power of $2$, but I cannot figure out why the number of ways to write an even integer as sum of $3$ power of primes is $O(N(\log N)^4)$.

**Here is what I have tried.**

for example, for $k_1$ we have $\log_2 N=O(\log N)$ possibilites, and the number of possibilites for $k_2$ is bounded by $$\log_2 N+\log_3 N+\log_4 N+ \dots \log_N N=\frac{\log N}{\log 3}+ \dots \frac{\log N}{\log N}=\log N\big( \sum_{i=3}^{N} \frac{1}{\log i} \big)=O(N \log N)$$. So the number of ways to express an even number is bounded by $N(\log N)^2$. Correct, Right? but Davenport writes $N(\log N)^4$ and I am unsure why?

Comment: HInt: let $i$ range over the numbers you've indicated, and let $k_2$ range over all possible prime-power values. Then $k_3$ is uniquely determined. What happens if you assume the worst—that $k_3$ is always a prime power?

Comment: @GregMartin, I am not sure how can I compute the number of prime powers less than or equal to $N$. One way I can think of it as $\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2 N} \pi(N^{\frac{1}{i}})$. Apart from that, I tried to get an upper bound but it does not match with what is written in the book. First of all, I have $\log_2 N$ possibilites for $k_1$ and then for $k_2$, we have $\pi(x) \log_2 N$ possibilites and this bound is not strict at all. However I have not been able to get what is written in the book.

Comment: for example, for $k_1$ we have $\log_2 N=O(\log N)$ possibilites, and the number of possibilites for $k_2$ is bounded by $\log_2 N+\log_3 N+\log_4 N+ \dots \log_N N=\frac{\log N}{\log 3}+ \dots \frac{\log N}{\log N}=\log N\big( \sum_{i=3}^{N} \frac{1}{\log i} \big)=O(N \log N)$. So the number of ways to express an even number is bounded by $N(\log N)^2$. This is correct, Right? but Davenport writes $N(\log N)^4$ and I am unsure why?

Comment: Note that $N\log N$ is a worse bound than the trivial bound $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $r(N)$ is not the number of representations of $N$ as the sum of three prime powers, but a weighted version of that:
$$
r(N) = \sum_{\substack{1\le k_1,k_2,k_3\le N \\ k_1+k_2+k_3=N}} \Lambda(k_1)\Lambda(k_2)\Lambda(k_3).
$$
Since we are aiming for a $O$-bound, we may permute the variables any way we wish (we lose at most a factor of $3!$ by doing so). So we may bound
$$
\sum_{\substack{1\le k_1,k_2,k_3\le N \\ k_1+k_2+k_3=N \\ k_1 \text{ is a power of }2 \\ k_2,k_3\text{ are prime powers}}} \Lambda(k_1)\Lambda(k_2)\Lambda(k_3) \ll (\log N)^3 \sum_{\substack{1\le k_1,k_2,k_3\le N \\ k_1+k_2+k_3=N \\ k_1 \text{ is a power of }2 \\ k_2,k_3\text{ are prime powers}}} 1.
$$
Since $k_3=N-k_1-k_2$ is uniquely determined by $k_1$ and $k_2$, we see that
\begin{align*}
r(N) &\ll (\log N)^3 \cdot \#\{\text{powers of $2$ less than $N$}\} \cdot \#\{\text{prime powers less than $N$}\} \\
&\ll (\log N)^3 \cdot \log N \cdot \frac N{\log N} = N(\log N)^3.
\end{align*}
The fact that the number of prime powers less than $N$ is $\ll N/\log N$ follows from
\begin{align*}
\#\{\text{prime powers less than $N$}\} &= \sum_{k=1}^{(\log N)/\log 2} \pi(N^{1/k}) \\
&= \pi(N) + \sum_{k=2}^{(\log N)/\log 2} \pi(N^{1/k}) \\
&\le \pi(N) + \sum_{k=2}^{(\log N)/\log 2} \pi(\sqrt N) \ll \frac N{\log N} + \log N\cdot \sqrt N.
\end{align*}